# where clause with if statement mysql query in codeigniter 2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

```
$this->db->where('if(`ledger_book`.is_pdc="1",`cheque_date`,`voucher_date` )<=', $to, false);
```

I am using the above query to work like described below:

If the "is_pdc" is set to 1 the condition should be executed with `cheque_date` else, it should use `voucher_date`.

The above query should be returned like this
if(`is_pdc`="1",`cheque_date` ,`voucher_date` )<='2017-02-13'
but my query does't show the quotes for the date.

I am using code-igniter 2.2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this change will helps you

```
$this->db->where('if(`ledger_book`.is_pdc="1",`cheque_date`,`voucher_date` )<=', '"'.$to.'"', false);
```